# How to make combobox select an item from the model?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, model

I am trying to do the update, In my update form there is combobox whose items comes from the model which is filled from the database.
Now what i am trying to do is that it selects the item automatically which is coming from the database of a specific record.

below is the code

```
public partial class UpdateCompanyForm : Form
{
    CompanyModel c = new CompanyModel();

    public UpdateCompanyForm(CompanyModel company)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        c = company;
    }

    private void UpdateCompanyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CompanyNameEnValue.Text = c.CompanyNameEn;

        SectorComboBox.DataSource = GlobalConfig.Connections.GetAll_Sector();
        SectorComboBox.SelectedItem = c.Sector;
        SectorComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";

        CategoryComboBox.DataSource = GlobalConfig.Connections.GetAll_Category();
        CategoryComboBox.SelectedItem = c.Category;

        CategoryComboBox.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
        PhoneNumberValue.Text = c.Contacts.PhoneNumber;

    }
}
```

I have 2 items in the SectorCombobox and 2 items in categorycombobox.
It is filled with by the database but i want it select a specific item.
You all know how update works.

Comment: Have you tried setting `SectorComboBox.SelectedValue` or `SectorComboBox.SelectedIndex`?

Comment: @JeremyThompson when using selected value I get this
"System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot set the SelectedValue in a ListControl with an empty ValueMember.'"
this is the change that i made
SectorComboBox.SelectedValue = c.Sector.Name;

Comment: Here is what I do:

`cb.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", fobject, "ValueToSet", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);`

Comment: @JeremyThompson Sir Can you explain, what should i write instead of selectedvalue and valuetoset. or should i just write as it is. I am quite confused.

Comment: Whenever you call a function/method you're not sure what to pass it, check what arguments the functions parameter expects. You use intellisense to see the signature, and give the function the arguments it expects. This is a general programming tip that applies to any language with intellisense.